# Correlated join with outer fields as parameters

Tags: sql, join, correlated-subquery

I need a way to join a table with a function's results. I'm not sure if it's possible and somehow I don't think it's a good idea. Let me try and explain the situation.

There is a table [Entities]:

```
[ID]    [Description]    [kWh]    [kVArh]    [kVAh]    [OfferID]    [CustomOfferID]
```

Another table [Data]:

```
[ID]    [Timestamp]    [Value]
```

And a function:

```
[Calc] (@offer, @customOffer, @kWh, @kVArh, @kVAh, @dtStart, @dtEnd)
```

So you can see there are entities, the entities' data (usage) and a function to calculate the cost.

I need to display the usage and cost of multiple entites:

```
[Description]    [MWh]    [MVA]    [Cost]
```

`[MWh]` will be a SUM of all the entity's data over the period; `[MVA]` will be the MAX of all the data over the period; and `[Cost]` will SUM the `[Cost]` field from the sub query (function).

The query I figured would do the jobs looks like this:

```
SELECT [tc].[ID], [tc].[Desc]
    , SUM([kWh].[Value]) / 1000 AS [MWh]
    , MAX([kVAh].[Value]) / 1000 AS [MVA]
    , SUM([cost].[Cost])
FROM [Tree_Cost] AS [tc]
INNER JOIN [Data] AS [kWh] ON [tc].[kWh] = [kWh].[ID]
INNER JOIN [Data] AS [kVAh] ON [tc].[kVAh] = [kVAh].[ID]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [tc].[ID], [Cost]
    FROM [Calc] ([tc].[Offer_ID], [tc].[OfferCustom_ID], [tc].[kWh], [tc].[KVArh], [tc].[kVAh], @dtStart, @dtEnd)
) AS [cost] ON [tc].[ID] = [cost].[ID]
WHERE [tc].[Type] = 1 AND [tc].[TypeDesc] = 'GF_K_M'
AND [kWh].[Timestamp] BETWEEN @dtStart AND @dtEnd
AND [kVAh].[Timestamp] BETWEEN @dtStart AND @dtEnd
GROUP BY [tc].[ID], [tc].[Desc]
```

The real problem here is that I need to include the `[ID]` from the outer query in the result set of the inner query (function) in order to be able to join the two. Then I also need to be able to use the fields from the outer query as arguments for the inner query (function).

This is obviously not the way seeing as the `[tc]` identifier is not recognized in the inner query. So how am I supposed to accomplish something like this?

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Calc]
  ( \@intOffer [int]
  , \@intCustom [int]
  , \@intP [int]
  , \@intQ [int]
  , \@intS [int]
  , \@dtStart [datetime]
  , \@dtEnd [datetime]
  )
RETURNS TABLE
      ( [Entry] [nvarchar](200) NULL
      , [Rate] [float] NULL
      , [Unit] [nvarchar](50) NULL
      , [Reading] [float] NULL
      , [Cost] [float] NULL
      , [DDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL
      )
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS EXTERNAL NAME [OfferCalcLite].[UserDefinedFunctions].[SqlArray]
```

Comment: @ypercube: "And a funtion: `[Calc] (@offer, @customOffer, @kWh, @kVArh, @kVAh, @dtStart, @dtEnd)`"

Comment: @cularis: I'm trying to figure out where this function is used. @that0th3rGuy: Is it used to calculate `[Cost]`?

Comment: yes, `[Calc]` is a function is the database which has fields `[Description] [Unit] [Rate] [Cost] [Comment]` and it return a couple of rows; sorry for not begin clear about that. so then `[Cost]` (in the main query), i thought, could be generated with `SUM`

Comment: Can you post the definition of `[Calc]`?

Comment: i'm sorry, by definition, do you mean (sorry for poor formatting):

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Calc](\@intOffer [int], \@intCustom [int], \@intP [int], \@intQ [int], \@intS [int], \@dtStart [datetime], \@dtEnd [datetime])
    RETURNS  TABLE (
     [Entry] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
     [Rate] [float] NULL,
     [Unit] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [Reading] [float] NULL,
     [Cost] [float] NULL,
     [DDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    ) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS 
    EXTERNAL NAME [OfferCalcLite].[UserDefinedFunctions].[SqlArray]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. Perhaps you can completely drop the JOIN:

```
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [tc].[ID], [Cost]
    FROM [Calc] ([tc].[Offer_ID], [tc].[OfferCustom_ID], [tc].[kWh], [tc].[KVArh], [tc].[kVAh], @dtStart, @dtEnd)
) AS [cost] ON [tc].[ID] = [cost].[ID]
```

and change:

```
, SUM([cost].[Cost])
```

into:

```
, SUM( [Calc] ( [tc].[Offer_ID]
              , [tc].[OfferCustom_ID]
              , [tc].[kWh]
              , [tc].[KVArh]
              , [tc].[kVAh]
              , @dtStart, @dtEnd
              )
     ) AS Cost
```

Comment: thanx for responding. i apologize for not begin clear previously. the `[Calc]` function returns a result set with multiple columns so i altered your suggestion as follows: `, ( SELECT SUM([Cost]) AS [Cost] FROM [Calc] (...)) AS [Cost]` although it produced an error: "...could not produce a query plan."; i'll try and see what i can find about this error. thanx again.

Comment: i get "incorrect syntax". is `SELECT SUM(<function>({arguments}))` where `<function>({arguments})` returns multiple columns valid? don't i need to specify the column to sum?

Comment: OK, if you can make another function (say, `CalcCost`) that only returns one result, then you could use my suggestion.

Comment: Could work but unfortunately a new function is not an option. I have, however, found a solution. It involves your suggestion which I altered. The reason for the "could not produce a query plan" error was because I was using the outer query's fields as arguments, but I did not include them in the `GROUP BY` clause. Thanx for you time!